# Error with array_foreach when using together with aggregate in QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, expression, array, aggregate, qgis-expression

I want to use array_foreach functionality. But it does not seems to work when used in an aggregate function.

This intermediate test ( array predefined, instead of array generated by another aggregate), is as follows:

```
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(array(208,209),
    ' ' || @element || ': '|| 
        aggregate(layer:= @z_PanneauxBase,
                aggregate:='concatenate',
                expression:=to_string("pa_uid"), 
                filter:= "Refpiquet" = @element,
                concatenator:='-')
) 
)
```

The response is `' 208: 1384-1385, 209: 1384-1385'` ! strange: the same result for both elements of the array. The @element exported as text in the concatenation seems the correct one. And by the way the answer is wrong for both.

What did I do wrong, is `@element` supposed to work within an aggregate process?

For info, the syntax is shown as correct by the expression string builder.

Replacing the predefined array, by an aggregate function giving a similar array, gives the same error result.

QGIS, version LTR 3.28.4, using shapefiles.

Comment: We need the data structure you use to be able to see what goes wrong and the desired result. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: yes of course, but how to send you the shapefiles? for infon Refpiquet is a dynamic field

Comment: Post it to a cloud service and share the link here

Comment: Here is the link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VJMR6lN4SjG7TP18xhm3kAZ1CClhTNb5?usp=sharing

Comment: You provided a project with many layers. No idea what you want to do with the expression, where you try to apply it or what you want to achieve. You should tell us as clear as possible what you try to do. You should also provide a minimal reproducilble example, a simplified version of your project that only contains the minimal data to be able to understand the problem. Everything elso just adds to the confusion.

Comment: I added a text file explanation in the same cloud directory with the shapefiles
at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VJMR6lN4SjG7TP18xhm3kAZ1CClhTNb5?usp=sharing

Comment: Was the explanation file OK to understand or reproduce the problem ?

Comment: No, the file does not help. There are many layers missing in the project. Try to create a sample project as easy and small as possible to demonstrate only the problem, nothing else. If you have too many layers that are unnecessary, one doesn't know where to start.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the behavior with a single layer and two different "id" fields. it produces the same issue. no luck yet though

Comment: So it looks like a bug !!! What to do now ?? IS there a process to report bugs?

Comment: Looks like there is already a reported bug for this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54159

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug with `array_foreach` and `aggregate`. As a workaround, using nested `array_foreach` may work, as in this question: [QGIS functions: aggregate and array_foreach not working for vertices](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/476151/qgis-functions-aggregate-and-array-foreach-not-working-for-vertices)

I mocked up some panel data similar to yours:

Panel:

[image]

Start by building two arrays - the panels (`@panel`) and stakes (`@stake`).

Then loop through each of these checking if the `stake_id` matches. There is a step to store the outer `@element` variable in a different variable (`@stake_element`)

In addition, there are extra functions to reduce the arrays to strings (`array_to_string`), and to filter out non-NULL values (`array_remove_all`) in order to get the final output, but these can be removed if you are just trying to understand the core nested loop.

```
with_variable('panel',
    aggregate('Panel',
    aggregate:='array_agg',
    expression:=@feature
),
with_variable('stake',array(208,209),
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(@stake,
        with_variable('stake_element',@element,
            @stake_element ||':'|| 
                array_to_string(
                    array_remove_all(
                        array_foreach(@panel,
                            if(attribute(@element,'stake_id')=@stake_element,
                            attribute(@element,'panel_id'),
                            NULL)
                        ),value:=NULL
                    ),'-'
                ))))))
```

Result is:

'208:1194-1195,209:1196-1197'