# QGIS functions: aggregate and array_foreach not working for vertices

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, vertices, qgis-expression, aggregate

I have two layers as the whole project in EPSG:4326:

- polygon layer of countries
- linestring layer of routes

I want to concatenate the country names (those are stored in `"name"` attribute) based on intersection with linestring vertices ordered by linestring vertices order.

In my example (vertices numbered with vertex number) I'm expecting the result something like this:

- for red route: Czech Republic, Slovakia, Hungary, Austria
- for blue route: Slovakia, Poland, Czech Republic
  (no matter if result will be arrayed of strings or string, I can handle it later)

[image]

I made the various expressions that allow me to get the country names for a particular vertex number, but the concatenation is a problem.
I made an expression that iterates over the vertices and for each vertex it should concatenate the intersection country name, here is the code:

```sql
array_foreach(
    geometries_to_array(nodes_to_points($geometry)),
    with_variable(
        'n_point',
        @element,
        aggregate(layer:='countries',
        aggregate:='concatenate',
        expression:="name", 
        filter:=intersects($geometry, n_point)
        )
    )
)
```

I'm on Win 11 Pro, version 23H2; QGIS 3.28.13

I found [Error with array_foreach when using together with aggregate in QGIS expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469866/error-with-array-foreach-when-using-together-with-aggregate-in-qgis-expression) that deals with similar problem as it seems to be the problem/bug of aggregate + array_foreach usage

Can provide the project with dataset if necessary.

Comment: In your filter expression, it should be `@n_point`, however I did not find a way to have it work (I end-up with as many points that the line has but with the name of le last country repeated as many times)

Comment: Looks like there is already a reported bug for this: github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/54159

Answer (score 4):

You can work around the array/aggregate issue by using nested `array_foreach` loops. It looks pretty ugly but it spits out the right results for your test dataset!

The trick - which I've never tried before, but which does seem to work - is to assign the `@element` variable in the outer loop to a new variable, before starting the inner loop. In this case I've used `@pt_element`. QGIS seems to reserve the `@element` variable for use in the innermost loop.

So we start by building our two arrays - the list of country features (`@countries`), and the list of vertices, as per the original question (`@vertices`).

We then loop through the `@vertices` and the `@countries` checking whether a vertex is in that country (`within`). I've used `array_max` as a crude way of filtering out the non-`NULL` values and leaving only the country name that matches the point. There might be cleaner ways.

```
with_variable('countries',
    aggregate('countries',
              aggregate:='array_agg',
              expression:=@feature
              ),
with_variable('vertices',geometries_to_array(nodes_to_points(@geometry)),
array_foreach(@vertices,
    with_variable('pt_element',@element,
    array_max(
        array_foreach(
            @countries,
            if(
                within(@pt_element,geometry(@element))
            ,attribute(@element,'name'),NULL)
        ))))))
```

Output as a label (when wrapped in `array_to_string`):

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! I have tried nested loops before with no success. This opens up a world of possibilities. I just tested it successfully for making a grid of points using Geometry Generator.

Comment: @Matt - yeah, I got quite excited when I found that it worked! There are always some problems that seem to run up against the limits of expressions. This seems to push the boundaries a bit.

Answer (score 2):

First i tried this code, which works and get the countries BUT it's not ordered. Because the the intersection order is ordered by the polygons and not by the nodes.

```
  aggregate(
        layer:= 'countries',
        aggregate:='concatenate',
        expression:="name",
        concatenator:=', ',
        filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
    )
```

[image]

So i think it have to be done in python. Order is the drawing order.

```
lyrRoutes = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('routes')[0]
lyrCountries = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('countries')[0]

lyrRoutesCountries_idx = lyrRoutes.fields().indexOf('countries')
lyrCountriesName_idx = lyrCountries.fields().indexOf('NAME')

routepoint = QgsFeature()

with edit(lyrRoutes):
    for route in lyrRoutes.getFeatures():
        route_id = route.id()
        countries_list = []
        route_countries = route.attributes()[lyrRoutesCountries_idx]
        geom = route.geometry()
        for part in geom.parts():
            for p in part.vertices():
                print(p)
                routepoint.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromQPointF(p.toQPointF()))
                for country in lyrCountries.getFeatures():
                    country_name = country.attributes()[lyrCountriesName_idx]
                    if routepoint.geometry().within(country.geometry()):
                        countries_list.append(country_name)
                    countries_string = ', '.join(countries_list)
        print(countries_string)
        route['countries'] = countries_string
        lyrRoutes.updateFeature(route)
    
print(countries_list)
```

[image]